# Due to an occasional exception, shoud I ignore an exception in Htmlunit

Tags: java, exception, htmlunit

I used Htmiunit to write a method snippet to log out from a social webpage, which is listed below:

```
private void logoutWeibo(){

    String WeiboLogoutURL = "http://login.sina.com.cn/sso/logout.php?";
    HtmlPage WeiboLogoutPage = null;
    do{
        try {
            WeiboLogoutPage = client.getPage(WeiboLogoutURL);
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException | IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }while(WeiboLogoutPage.getElementById("username") == null);


}
```

Occasionally, the statement "**WeiboLogoutPage = client.getPage(WeiboLogoutURL);**" would throw an IOException due to connection timeout. I'm willing to ignore it and ask the program to continue.
Should I ignore it and could I fulfill it by re-writing the code snippet like this:

```
private void logoutWeibo(){

    String WeiboLogoutURL = "http://login.sina.com.cn/sso/logout.php?";
    HtmlPage WeiboLogoutPage = null;
    int errorTimeout = 0;
    do{
        try {
            WeiboLogoutPage = client.getPage(WeiboLogoutURL);
        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if(errorTimeout++ > 5){
                break;
            }
            else{
                logoutWeibo();  
            }
        }
    }while(WeiboLogoutPage.getElementById("username") == null);


}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you testing someone elses website? If so, why?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke I'm not testing the website. I just used the htmlunit class to write an automation program to log out from the website. The process of logging out from the specific website is just one part of my automation posting program. I wanted to avoid the error caused by incidental timeout and kept the program running down to the next step. That's why I added some conditional statement.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's still not entirely clear why your test case is dependent on being able to log out in some cases, but not in other cases (when it times out). If the test can succeed, regardless of the outcome of the logout attempt, why even bother doing it in the first place?

Comment: @MikkelLøkke why do you think of Htmlunit as a testing tool? I don't use it as a testing tool. I used it to post in a forum automatically. Does it make sense?

Comment: I think of HTMLUnit as a testing tool, because it doesn't really work as a headless browser on any modern webpage (ie. AJAX), so its usefulness IMHO is limited to testing sites that you know does not rely on JavaScript for content.

Answer (score 0):

There are several items to be noted here.

1. How critical is this webpage.

   - If this webpage is not critical, it may probably be okay to ignore the error
2. How much downtime is okay.

   - If your website is expected to be down for longer period of times, you will have to ignore if the server is down.

So, depending on the answers to above question, you will have to repeat. Your first code already ignores the exception and won't report any failure because you are catching the exception. But it will keep looking for username forever.

It is okay to repeat it for certain number of times as you wanted to do it in your second piece of code, however as you have mixed both a loop and recursion, this can also potentially lead to an infinite loop. Remove the else block inside catch to come out of the loop if username is not found for 5 times.

Another suggestion is that you better keep some sleep between each try so that you don't try to contact the webpage too frequently. Like say keep a gap of five seconds or so to increase chance of the script to pass.